# Windows keyboard hook hangs debugger

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, keyboard, hook

I have a plug-in DLL that is launched from a secondary (not GUI) thread in the main application.  The DLL must grab keyboard events from the application's main window.  I am using `SetWindowsHookEx()` and it works great.

However, if I hit a breakpoint in Visual Studio while the hook is active, and then press a key, Visual Studio and my application lock up completely.  This is a problem because I usually use the F-keys to step through code.  If I use the mouse and step forward from Visual Studio's Debug menu, it works fine.  But using F10 et al. is such a habit, I usually forget to use the mouse.

Is there anything I can do to get my keyboard shortcuts back?  Or a different method to listen to the keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty inevitable, the debugger break stops the hook from handling notifications so the keyboard goes dead.  Using the remote debugger on another machine is a good way to debug code like this.  You'll also want to increase the hook timeout so Windows doesn't destroy the hook while you are debugging, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LowLevelHooksTimeout setting.  Assuming you are using WH_KEYBOARD_LL.