# Debugging in Microsoft Visual Studio slows PC to a crawl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to debug an open-source C++ application I've just downloaded (a VoIP program called Mumble, available from GitHub [here](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble)), but as soon as Visual Studio hits a breakpoint or I pause execution my whole system slows to a crawl.

I have noticed that if I'm patient enough to wait for the task manager to appear, then just after it has focus my system is back to normal. If I re-focus MSVC (or any other application it seems), then my system goes back to a crawl.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4), and the laptop I'm working from is no slouch (see below).

Some things I've tried:

- Loading/caching all debug symbols before starting a debug session
- Disabling automatic loading of debug symbols
- Setting the priority of msvc and/or the app higher/lower via task manager
- Setting the CPU affinity of msvc and the app to different sets of "CPUs"
- Disabling IntelliSense
- Deleting all breakpoints

Hardware details are:

- MSI GS60 2PC Notebook

  - Intel Core i7 Processor
  - 16GB RAM
  - 256GB SSD (Visual Studio installed here) + 1TB HDD (project hosted here)
  - NVIDIA GeForce GTX860 2GB Video Card
  - Windows 8.1

I'm at a loss, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the nature of that open-source app? Are there hooks involved? Anything related to device drivers?

Comment: @VladFeinstein The application is Mumble (a VoIP application) available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble).

It does use a hook to insert an overlay into DirectX / OpenGL applications.

Comment: post some details about your hardware.

Comment: Well, if you are in a chain of hooks, someone's call to CallNextHookEx() when you are the next hook will have to time-out (not sure what the time is). May this be the delay you see?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've added them to the original post.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Possibly. I'm normally developing in Java so coming into a C++ environment is a bit new for me. Is there something in particular I can search for to read up on how to manage that while debugging?

Comment: install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), run WPRui.exe, select CPU, Disk, FileIO, VAlloc and start the trace. Now start debugging until you hit a breakpoint and see the slowness. Go back to WPRui and save the trace into a ETL file. Zip the ETl + the NGENPDB folder (very important) and share th zip (OneDrive link). I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yeah, looking a trace in WPT is the thing I'd try as well. BTW: Bruce Dawson has lots on info on using WPT [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/etw-central/).

Comment: @magicandre1981 Apologies for the delay, it really took ages to upload it to OneDrive [here](http://1drv.ms/1Xi3ESG). I used a single breakpoint, started the debug session, started the trace, then performed an action that I knew would hit the breakpoint. I finally closed VS using the task manager and then saved the trace. Thanks very much for taking the time to have a look.

Comment: It seems the file is broken. I downloaded twice but could not extract

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sorry about that, the Internet here isn't the best. I've just finished uploading and downloading (to check it works) from Dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xfagdc420lx6qa/WPRFiles.zip?dl=0).  
  
It may ask you to register if you don't already have an account, but you can just click anywhere outside of the registration request box to skip it and download the file. I'll try OneDrive again in case people prefer that and post a link once it's done.

Comment: [OneDrive link](http://1drv.ms/1XiFNCm) tested and working.

Comment: Ok, the culprit was a couple of calls to SetWindowsHookEx, hooking the keyboard and mouse respectively. It makes perfect sense why this was messing up my debug sessions and is explained a little in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727327/windows-keyboard-hook-hangs-debugger) (in case anyone else comes across this question). In the end, this question is definitely a duplicate, and just came down to my own ignorance of the code I was trying to debug and C++ in general :) Many thanks for the comments, and for pointing me to WPT too.

Comment: ok. I thanks for the feedback. I looked at the ETL and was not really able to see this. Post it as answer.